# Send message to all channels

Tags: foreach, discord.js

How to send message to all channels in specific guild. I was trying to do something similar:

```
message.guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel)=>{

 message.channel.send('hello')

})
```

But the bot did not send messages to all channels, but only to one.
Discord.js v14

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no problems in it! You're just sending the message to the current channel..

```
message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => {
    if(!channel.isTextBased()) return;
    channel.send('hello')
})
```

Comment: Gives an error  ```TypeError: channel.send is not a function```

Comment: edited the code, it should work now